# Digit Counting in C

Tags: c

I can't find out the problem, it doesn't give me the right answer, for example: I put 1234567890, it gives me a series of strange number, I'm new so I cant post a picture:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    int m[10];

    while((n=getchar())!='\n') {
        ++m[n-'0'];
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;++i) {
        printf("%d\n",m[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see and what are you getting instead? Help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that you do not initialize the array
before counting digits.

```
int m[10] = {0};
```

Also you should handle non digit values so that the program
doesn't crash e.g.

```
while((n=getchar())!='\n')
{
  if ( isdigit(n) )
  {
    ++m[n-'0'];
  }
}
```

( isdigit() is available if you include ctype.h )

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array contents to 0 instead of whatever randomly happens to be in memory, using:

```
 int m[10]={0};
```

Answer (score 1):

A few folks have already suggested including

```
int m[10] = {0};
```

This will work. Depending upon your compiler and optimization options it *may* not lead to the "best" code. An alternative, that I prefer is to invoke memset() to initialize the array to 0's before using it. Here is the modified program (also note that you do not need both n and i but an optimizing compiler would take care of that too):

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* for getchar() and printf() */
#include <string.h> /* for memset() */
#include <ctype.h>  /* for isdigit() */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int n, m[11];

  memset(m, 0, sizeof(m)); /* initialize counters to zero's */

  while ((n=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    if (isdigit(n))
    {
      ++(m[n-'0']);
    }
    else
    {
      ++(m[10]);
    }
  }
  for(n=0;n<10;n++)
    printf("%c : %d\n",'0'+n, m[n]);
  printf("Filtered characters: %d\n",m[10]);

  return 0;
}
```

A sample run looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out
At 12:45 p.m. I ran to the 7-11 for a 48oz big gulp
0 : 0
1 : 3
2 : 1
3 : 0
4 : 2
5 : 1
6 : 0
7 : 1
8 : 1
9 : 0
Filtered characters: 42
$
```

As a final note, I looked at the generated assembly instructions output from gcc for different size m[]. Gcc generates inline code (sometimes looping and sometimes unrolled depending upon optimizations) for small sized arrays (say m[10] = {0};) and generates invocations of memset() as I have shown for larger sized arrays (say m[100] = {0};). A conclusion that can be drawn from this is that leaving the code as m[10] = {0}; allows the compiler to choose the best solution based upon what it knows about the target system which is almost certainly more than what you know.

Answer (score -1):

Well since you didnt list what your problem is, I can only guess, but without trying to compile this, the most glaring issue is the buffer overflow on the "m" array. [Something which was wrong pointed out in the comments]

**Edit**
Also if you enter characters other than a number or newline, you'll overwrite memory outside the "m" array too.

Comment: Close, but it's what gets typed in rather than how much. `m` is not storing the characters, it's storing the counts for each character. But, if it gets a non-digit, it will attempt to write outside the rray bounds.

Comment: lol, yeah I noticed that and edited my post at the same time you added your comment. I saw the ++m, and for whatever reason thought m was a pointer even though I said it was an array (i'm tired).